# Calculator console app in Java

Tags: java, beginner

Here is my source code for my very first app in Java. I am completely new to the language; any help and criticism is welcomed!

```
package com.company;

import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    public static float multiply(float a, float b)
    {
        return a*b;
    }

    public static float divide(float a, float b)
    {
        return a/b;
    }

    public static float addition(float a, float b)
    {
        return a+b;
    }

    public static float subtraction(float a, float b)
    {
        return a-b;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner scanner;
        float firstNum, secondNum, result;
        String operation;

        scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(true){
            System.out.println("Select operation (*,/,+,-)");
            operation = scanner.next();
            if (operation.matches("[*/+-]")) {
                break;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Invalid operation");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Type in first number");
        firstNum = scanner.nextFloat();

        System.out.println("Type in second number");
        secondNum = scanner.nextFloat();

        switch(operation)
        {
            case "*": result = multiply(firstNum, secondNum); break;
            case "/": result = divide(firstNum, secondNum); break;
            case "+": result = addition(firstNum, secondNum); break;
            case "-": result = subtraction(firstNum, secondNum); break;
            default: result = 0;
        }

        System.out.println("Result of your operation is " + result);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're interested in how to implement more complex expressions with operator precedence etc. take a look at the "expr" program in Gnu coreutils project. https://github.com/coreutils It's C but it's quite easily translated to Java. Instead of asking for input you could just require it as command line arguments like the aforementioned Gnu tool does. If you're reading input from console as an exercise, it's a lesson that has practically zero payout. I have never had to read user input from console during my 25 years as software developer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a first application in Java, good job!

I have some suggestions for your code.

### When using regex, try to uses the `java.util.regex.Pattern` class instead of the `java.lang.String#matches` method.

When using the `java.lang.String#matches` method, the regex pattern is recompiled each time the method is called. This can cause a slowdown in your method execution.

**How to uses the matcher**

```java
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[*/+-]");
while (true) {
   //[...]
   if (pattern.matcher(operation).matches()) {
      //[...]
   }
   //[...]
}
```

### Extract some of the logic to methods.

Extracting code can make the code shorter and easier to read. Also when you have logic that does the same thing, you can generally move it into a method and reuse it.

- You can make a method that asks a question and read the next float; this will allow you to reuse the same method.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
   //[...]
   firstNum = askQuestionAndReceiveFloat(scanner, "Type in first number");
   secondNum = askQuestionAndReceiveFloat(scanner, "Type in second number");
   //[...]
}

private static float askQuestionAndReceiveFloat(Scanner scanner, String question) {
   System.out.println(question);
   return scanner.nextFloat();
}
```

- You can extract the logic to parse the operation.

```java
private static String askForOperation(Pattern pattern, Scanner scanner) {
   String operation;
   while (true) {
      System.out.println("Select operation (*,/,+,-)");
      operation = scanner.next();

      if (pattern.matcher(operation).matches()) {
         break;
      } else {
         System.out.println("Invalid operation");
      }
   }
   return operation;
}
```

- If you are using Java 14, you can use the newer version of the [`switch-case`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/language/switch-expressions.html) and return the value.

```java
private static float getResult(float firstNum, float secondNum, String operation) {
   return switch (operation) {
      case "*" -> multiply(firstNum, secondNum);
      case "/" -> divide(firstNum, secondNum);
      case "+" -> addition(firstNum, secondNum);
      case "-" -> subtraction(firstNum, secondNum);
      default -> 0;
   };
}
```

Those's changes will make the main method shorter and easier to read!

### Use `java.io.PrintStream#printf` instead of `java.io.PrintStream#println` when you have to concatenate

`java.io.PrintStream#printf` offer you to use [patterns](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Formatter.html) to build the string without concatenating it manually. The only downside is you will be forced to add the break line character yourself; in java you can use the `%n` to break the line (portable between various platforms) or uses the traditional `\n` / `\r\n`.

```java
System.out.printf("Result of your operation is %s%n", result);
```

## Refactored code

```java
public static float multiply(float a, float b) {
   return a * b;
}

public static float divide(float a, float b) {
   return a / b;
}

public static float addition(float a, float b) {
   return a + b;
}

public static float subtraction(float a, float b) {
   return a - b;
}

private static float askQuestionAndReceiveFloat(Scanner scanner, String question) {
   System.out.println(question);
   return scanner.nextFloat();
}

private static String askForOperation(Pattern pattern, Scanner scanner) {
   String operation;
   while (true) {
      System.out.println("Select operation (*,/,+,-)");
      operation = scanner.next();

      if (pattern.matcher(operation).matches()) {
         break;
      } else {
         System.out.println("Invalid operation");
      }
   }
   return operation;
}

private static float getResult(float firstNum, float secondNum, String operation) {
   return switch (operation) {
      case "*" -> multiply(firstNum, secondNum);
      case "/" -> divide(firstNum, secondNum);
      case "+" -> addition(firstNum, secondNum);
      case "-" -> subtraction(firstNum, secondNum);
      default -> 0;
   };
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
   Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[*/+-]");
   Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
   float firstNum, secondNum, result;
   String operation = askForOperation(pattern, scanner);

   firstNum = askQuestionAndReceiveFloat(scanner, "Type in first number");
   secondNum = askQuestionAndReceiveFloat(scanner, "Type in second number");
   result = getResult(firstNum, secondNum, operation);

   System.out.printf("Result of your operation is %s%n", result);
}
```

Also, I suggest to handle the `x / 0` case :)

Comment: Many thanks! Very "verbose" comments :) I have a lot to learn from this